# Как в ExpandableListView сохранять/восстанавливать view вместо пересоздания?

Tags: expandablelistview, android, view

Есть `ExpandableList`. В нем все группы разные, `child`'ы у каждой группы тоже свои, причем некоторые имеют довольно нагруженный `layout` (присутствуют "трогательные" элементы - кнопки, чекбоксы, spinner), так что при прокрутке список притормаживает. При этом групп и `child`'ов мало (хотя в экран и не входят), поэтому я считаю разумным не создавать для них `View` каждый раз, а сохранить после первого создания и далее просто восстанавливать (тем более что при одном обновлении списка он каждый `view` не по одному разу запрашивает).
Проблема состоит в следующем:
Когда `view` каждый раз создается, то все работает правильно: нажатия отрабатываются и все остальные взаимодействия с экраном срабатывают сразу и правильно. Но вот когда я сохраняю `view` и в `getChildView` возвращаю этот сохраненный, происходит следующее. Когда я нажимаю кнопку, располагающуюся внутри, то сразу ничего не происходит. Только когда я начинаю прокручивать список, тогда отрабатывается нажатие на ту кнопку. Еще одна особенность, о которой стоит упомянуть: сразу после появления (например, я прокрутил список, чтобы `child` исчез с экрана, а потом обратно, соответственно `getChildView` достал сохраненный `view`) первое касание `child` отрабатывает сразу (как должно), а второе и последующие опять так же. Все описанное справедливо и для остальных clickable элементов.
Немного кода адаптера:

```
CartExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    ArrayList children; // массив с сохраненными view
...

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (children.size()<=groupPosition) children.add(new ArrayList<View>());
        switch (groupPosition){
            case 0: // dishes
// дальше создается view для группы, их пока не трогал
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (children.size()>groupPosition)
        {
            if (((ArrayList)children.get(groupPosition)).size()>childPosition) {
                convertView = (View)((ArrayList)children.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
                return convertView;
            }
        }
        else children.add(groupPosition,new ArrayList<View>());
        boolean createView = true;

        switch (groupPosition){
            case 0:
// тут создается view в зависимости от группы, которой он принадлежит

        }
        ((ArrayList) children.get(groupPosition)).add(convertView);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Подозреваю, что причина описанного явления где-то в природе класса `View`. Его я, возможно, знаю недостаточно хорошо. Я перепробовал установку для `view` статусов `focusable`, `activated`, ещё `setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES)`, ничего не менялось. Ума не приложу, отчего такое поведение.

Comment: Почитайте про адаптеры и как их использовать. Сохранять view в корне не верно.

Comment: Проблема производительности списка решена, ответ принят. Все равно интересна причина описанного поведения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно ручками их кешировать. Это правило. Вы его нарушили и получили странное. На самом деле нужно просто проверять convertView, которое Вам приходит в getChildView и если оно не NULL, то просто инициализировать правильными значениями. Но так как у Вас разные плашки (элементы списка) в списке, то список должен знать, какую именно плашку подсунуть. Для этого есть два воспомогательные метода [getChildTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildTypeCount()) и [getChildType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html#getChildType(int, int)). Первый возвращает количество "различных типов плашек". Второй возвращает, какой тип плашки нужен в данном месте. Если правильно подсунете тип, то в getChildView придет view нужного типа.

а `getChildView` будет такой

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == NULL) {
          // тут создаете view)
        }
        а тут обычная инициализация всех полей.
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Про childType в обычном ListView знал и использовал. Не додумался, как эти методы можно в раскрывающемся списке использовать. А сейчас заглянул в BaseExpandableListAdapter и все стало ясно. Кроме того, я думал, что когда view пропадает с экрана, он идет на переработку следующему появляющемуся, а если типы не совпадут, то просто пропадет.
В общем, спасибо за обстоятельный ответ, проблема производительности списка решена.
И все же я столько времени потратил в поисках источника этого "странного", что мне уже безумно интересно все же докопаться до истины.

Comment: До какой истинны Вы хотите докопаться?

Comment: Я услышал "сохранять view в корне не верно" и, пожалуй, слышал не один раз. Но ни разу, почему. Чем созданный в getChildView отличается от того, который я сохранил в массиве, ведь он был создан в этом же методе? Почему они по-разному себя ведут? Теряется связь с listener'ами или они сами теряются, когда view отсоединяют от родителя?

Comment: потому что listview сам умеет их кешировать и переиспользовать. Код внутри listview не рассчитывает на то, что кто то будет ещё кешировать.

Если хотите больше - ковыряйте сорцы андроида - они доступны и увлекательны. А просто так в коментариях всего не рассказать.

рекомендую посмотреть [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). Хотя оно 2010 года, но оно все же актуально и отвечает на многие вопросы.